# Azure Iterate through Blobs in a container

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, blob, blobstorage

I'm trying through iterate through blobs from a container, but I'm getting errors. I'm using the following code from Microsoft Docs:
One of the main errors I'm getting is when calling the ToListAsync() method

```
// Iterate through the blobs in a container
List<BlobItem> segment = await blobContainer.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: "").ToListAsync();
foreach (BlobItem blobItem in segment)
{
    BlobClient blob = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
    // Check the source file's metadata
    Response<BlobProperties> propertiesResponse = await blob.GetPropertiesAsync();
    BlobProperties properties = propertiesResponse.Value;
    
    // Check the last modified date and time
    // Add the blob to the list if has been modified since the specified date and time
    if (DateTimeOffset.Compare(properties.LastModified.ToUniversalTime(), transferBlobsModifiedSince.ToUniversalTime()) > 0)
    {
        blobList.Add(blob);
    }
}
```

These are the errors:
[image]

[image]

Comment: **What** is the error? Please provide the exact text of the error message and indicate what line it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/pagination#use-systemlinqasync-with-asyncpageable

> The [System.Linq.Async package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) provides a set of LINQ methods that operate on `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` type. Because `AsyncPageable<T>` implements `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, you can use `System.Linq.Async` to query and transform the data.

So make sure you have the System.Linq.Async package included in your project, along with a `using System.Linq.Async;` directive in your C# file.

Just be aware that there's a reason this is using an `IAsyncEnumerable<>`: if you have a lot of blobs it might be better to *stream* your way through the collection rather than loading all the values into an in-memory list.

```
IAsyncEnumerable<BlobItem> segment = blobContainer.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: "");
await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in segment)
{
    ...
}
```